# How can I use Unicode in Android Keyboard XML?

Tags: android, xml, unicode, keyboard, escaping

According to Keyboard.Key [android:codes](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/Keyboard.Key.html#attr_android:codes), [android:keyLabel](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/Keyboard.Key.html#attr_android:keyLabel), and [android:keyOutputText](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/Keyboard.Key.html#attr_android:keyOutputText), I can use Unicode in these fields.

> May be a string value, using '\;' to escape characters such as '\n' or '\uxxxx' for a unicode character;

In my code, I have tried

```
<Key android:codes="\\u2460;" android:keyLabel="\\u2460;"/>
<Key android:codes="\\u2460" android:keyLabel="\\u2460"/> <!-- no semi -->
```

Which didn't work. So then I tried

```
<Key android:codes="\u2460" android:keyLabel="\u2460"/> <!-- no double slash -->
```

This worked but only for the `keyLabel`. Neither `codes` nor `keyOutputText` cause anything to be outputted.

I even tried moving it over to `strings.xml`

```
<string name="one">\u2460</string>
```

Which again only works for the `keyLabel`.

How do I get this to output what I want?

**Note**: For those curious, `2460` is an encircled one.

Answer (score 0):

Documentation uses single quotes `'\\u2460;'` you are using double quotes `"\\u2460;"`.

*Disclaimer: I have no idea if that will help as I have not tried but I thought I should mention it*